# Overwrite All functions in my Function App Azure

Tags: azure, function

Make a deploy in visual Studio for an existing Function App and all of my function insed they disappeared

how can i get them back? is there any way to go back?

Answer (score 0):

As discussed [here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/18258), you can't get them back when you haven't done a manual snapshot of the file share before.